# Dynamic prog. Algo Rectangle Packaging

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have an assignment problem

> You are given a set of n 2-dimensional rectangles. You need to find a
>   maximum possible packaging of subset of rectangles. By packaging we
>   mean to place a smaller rectangle Ri within a larger rectangle Rj if
>   dimension conform for doing so. For example if there are four
>   rectangles R1(2,3),R2(2,4),R3(4,5) and R4(5,7) then the largest
>   possible packaging is of size 3 which is {R4 <- R3 <-R1} or {R4 <-R3
>   <- R2} Design a dynamic programming algorithm for finding the largest
>   size of packaging for any given set of rectangles.

I am going to solve this by comparing dimensions and counting if one rectangle has smaller dimensions so that it can be packaged.

Now as a learner my question is what different approach must have to be taken due to the presence of this sentence **"Design a dynamic programming algorithm "**
To me this sentence doesn't effecting my approach. I mean the only clue coming to my mind to solve this problem is the one I have mentioned.

Assistance required.

I used the following code;

```
package com.example.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RectangleTest {
    public double height;
    public double width;

    public RectangleTest(double width, double height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    public boolean canPutInside(RectangleTest r){
        if (this.width < r.width && this.height < r.height)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<RectangleTest> rectangles = new ArrayList<RectangleTest>();
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(2  , 3 ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(2  , 4 ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(4  , 5 ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(5  , 7 ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(8  , 3 ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(26 , 4 ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(44 , 5 ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(5  , 1 ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(2  , 31    ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(21 , 4 ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(6  , 51    ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(7  , 7 ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(12 , 3 ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(31 , 4 ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(4  , 33    ));
        rectangles.add(new RectangleTest(1, 7   ));
        int highestPackaging = 0;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < rectangles.size() - 1 ; i++){
            int count = 1;
            for(int q = i +1 ; q < rectangles.size() ;q++){
                if(rectangles.get(i).canPutInside(rectangles.get(q)))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(highestPackaging < count){
                highestPackaging = count;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Highest packaging size = "+ highestPackaging);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the approach you're trying? It sounds sort of greedy (not sure, not much detail), are you sure it's optimal?

Comment: i think I am simply getting brute force ..i am going to check something like if(this.height<height & this.width< width){ // some work}

Comment: To me it seems you are doing a greedy approach - that smells not optimal to me

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand the problem, can you define the input better?

Comment: I have updated the question...actually this is what I am confuse about, what the dynamic prog approach makes difference so that we can distinguish the two solutions

Comment: Roughly it means that it can be expressed as a recursive algorithm that solves "bigger problems" optimally using the optimal solutions to "smaller problems" (optimal substructure), and some "smaller problems" are generated multiple times (overlapping subproblems). Your algorithm should have this form. Often the recursion/memoization is rewritten to loops and an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a variant of the [longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).

Assuming it's OK to rotate the rectangles in order to fit them together, you can regard each rectangle as a point in a 2D scatter plot where *x* (width) ≥ *y* (height):

```
  |                             .        
  |                           .          
  |                         .            
  |                       .    A         
  |                     .                
  |                   .   B           C  
  |                 .         D          
y |               .                      
  |             .   E                    
  |           .            F            G
  |         .          H         I       
  |       .                              
  |     .        J          K            
  |   .    L        M                    
  | .        N         O                 
  +--------------------------------------
                     x
```

Your task is to find the longest path in the graph formed by these points (nodes), subject to the constraint that links can only be extended to other nodes with smaller *x* and *y* coordinates without bypassing any other nodes. For example, node `A` can link to nodes `B` and `D`, but not to node `F` because `D` lies in the rectangle bounded by `F` and `A` at opposite corners.

Associate each node with a number representing the maximum depth of the path extending from that node, and memoize these values as you go along. The answer should then appear fairly quickly.

Comment: hmm your answer really gives me another way to look at this problem...I did  some paper work with the given example ...so again a little query ..when I am going to put constraints and going to check x and y for each point does it remain optimal ? or I mean what should be the optimal way you point .

Comment: @SSH:It seems to give the optimum but why sort the boxes? This isn't very helpful.